# Is "because" the best way to describe the meaning of ὅτι in the Prologue?

Tags: greek, john

The Prologue in John's Gospel uses the conjunction **ὅτι** with three successive statements.

John 1:15-17 (ESV)

> (John bore witness about him, and cried out, “This was he of whom I said, ‘He who comes after me ranks before me, **because** he was before me.’”)
> **For** from his fullness we have all received, grace upon grace.
> **For** the law was given through Moses; grace and truth came through Jesus Christ.

Three thoughts in succession are joined using the conjunction ὅτι.

1. John the Baptist states the one coming after him ranks higher **ὅτι** He was before
2. John the writer states **ὅτι** from His fullness he (and others) received grace upon grace
3. John the writer states **ὅτι** the law was given through Moses, grace and truth came through Jesus Christ

Does treating the conjunction the same in each statement makes the most sense?

1. Because He was before...I, the Baptist am less
2. Because from His fullness...we, the disciples received...
3. Because the law was given...grace and truth came...

Answer (score 2):

"because" is definitely suitable for capturing the causal relationship implied in the first statement ("He who comes after me ranks before me because he was before me")

According the BDAG here are the uses of: **ὅτι**

1. **marker of narrative or discourse content, direct or indirect, *that.***
2. **marker of explanatory clauses, *that***
3. **marker for introducing direct discourse.** In this case it is not to be rendered in English, but to be represented by quotation marks

---

4. **marker of causality- (a)** subordinating, ***because, since***
   (b) The subordination is oft. so loose that the transl. ***for*** recommends itself. Naturally the line betw. the two groups cannot be drawn with certainty: **Mt 7:13; 11:29; Lk 7:47** (on this pass. and 1J 3:14 s. Schwyzer II 646, w. ref. to II. 16, 34f: 'infer this from the fact that');**9:12; 13:31; 16:24; J 1:16f; 9:16; 1 Cor 1:25; 4:9; 10:17; 2 Cor 4:6; 7:8, 14; 1J 3:14.**
5. Special uses.....

The fourth one is the most important to this question therefore I've added the most to it.

The BDAG indicates that the subordination of ὅτι can occasionally be "loose," indicating that the relationship between the subordinate clause and the main clause might not always be clearly established. In fact, you'll notice that J 1:16f ('f' meaning = (and) following.) is listed among these. So both John 1:16 and 17 are included in this 'loose' category.  In these instances, the translator must use discretion in selecting a suitable translation.

Let's take one of the examples:

Matthew 7:13
New King James Version

> 13 “Enter by the narrow gate; **for** wide is the gate and broad is the
> way that leads to destruction, and there are many who go in by it.

Matthew 7:13
New International Version

> 13 “Enter through the narrow gate. **For** wide is the gate and broad
> is the road that leads to destruction, and many enter through it.

Matthew 7:13
King James Version

> 13 Enter ye in at the strait gate: **for** wide is the gate, and broad
> is the way, that leadeth to destruction, and many there be which go in
> thereat:

Matthew 7:13
New American Standard Bible

> 13 “Enter through the narrow gate; **for** the gate is wide and the
> way is broad that leads to destruction, and there are many who enter
> through it.

Matthew 7:13

> 13 “Enter by the narrow gate. **For** the gate is wide and the way is
> easy that leads to destruction, and those who enter by it are many.

**I will end with 3 notes:**

1. "For" tends to be slightly more formal and literary than "because," which may align better with the tone and call more attention to the passage.

> The difference is really one of emphasis: starting a new sentence with
> for tends to call more attention to the thought that it introduces. [[1]](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/for)

2. For this reason, "For" often provides a clearer link between the two clauses, making the connection between the cause and effect more apparent to the reader.
3. You will notice that in many translations of the Bible, (At least all the ones I quoted from) "for" has been traditionally used in passages like this, which contributes to the consistency within biblical language.

Comment: +1. I agree.  God answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering the conjunction *oti* as "because" in all three instances cannot 'work' except for the first occurrence. There it is equally true to say that "because he was before me..." as it is to say "for he was before me...". A reason is being given as to why Christ is ranked higher than John the Baptist, namely, that he was the *logos* who existed 'in the beginning', untold aeons before John was even born (as John 1:1-3 states). It seemed that John came first (in time), with Jesus born some six months or so later, but a spiritual truth is being opened up in verse 15, expanding upon verse 1 to show that it was the uncreated *logos* who became flesh. As a reason is being given, 'because' makes just as much sense as 'for'.

Note that when *oti* occurs in verse 30, Stephens and YLT both render it as 'because'. And it is the same statement, "After me doth come a man, who hath come before me, because he was before me" YLT.  This shows that 'because' is an acceptable rendition of *oti* in verses 15 and 30.

However, saying 'because' does not work the second time (verse 17) due to the Greek text having *kai* - 'and'. It is not *oti*. Certainly not in the Greek text of *The Englishmans Greek New Testament*, Robert Estienne [Stephens]. Likewise in the YLT, 'And' is the translated word; neither 'because' nor 'for'.

*Oti* begins verse 17 and needs to be renders 'For' as it is factually incorrect to say that "because the law was given by Moses..." therefore grace and truth came by Jesus Christ. It is not a reason that is being given. It is not a consequence that is stated. It is a comparison that is being made. "For, on the one hand..." but on the other hand..." There is a stark contrast between Mosaic law, and the grace and truth that comes through Jesus Christ. The Mosaic law could never lead to grace and truth. Yes, the Mosaic law was 'true' (it was no lie), but grace never resulted from all and any attempts to keep it, because nobody could, and so the law could only condemn sinners.

**Summary**

1 It makes sense to have 'for' and equally to have 'because' in verse 15.

2 It cannot make sense to have either 'for' or 'because' in verse 16 as the word is 'And'.

3 It can only make sense to have 'for' in verse 17 as it's a contrast, not a reason.

Comment: Apparently this is a textual variant. Some manuscripts have *oti* in all three places. So **because** the law came through Moses (it was necessary) for grace and the truth (of salvation) to come (another way) through Jesus. Then the meaning is like a Pauline “saved by grace” not by the law.

Comment: @RevelationLad  The text remained with 'oti 'only two times for about 1,800 years. It wasn’t until the late 19th century that different manuscripts were found and made to replace the originals. Those were the ‘textual variants’.

Comment: There are good reasons for understanding ὅτι in John 1:16, in addition to the manuscript evidence there is understanding the three statements were made with the same composition. Regardless of  ὅτι or καὶ in 1:16, how does that determine the meaning of because/for for 1:17?

Comment: @RevelationLad I answered that (above, last para.) and this conclusion, "3 It can only make sense to have 'for' in verse 17 as it's a contrast, not a reason." Your first comment to me shows you view that differently, so we shall just have to agree to differ.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding John 1:15-17, the OP asks, “Three thoughts in succession are joined using the conjunction ὅτι…Does treating the conjunction the same in each statement makes the most sense?” While the repetition of ὅτι does serve to connect the thoughts, I agree with the decision of the translators to differentiate the first ὅτι from the two that follow.

It is important to note the composition of vv14-16. Verse 14 begins a thought that is “interrupted” by the witness of John the Baptist in v15. The ESV places v15 in parentheses for this reason. If we skip over v15 while read vv14-16, we can see more clearly why “because” is not the best rendering for ὅτι in vv16-17.

Whereas “because” with its causal implication fits in the context of v15, "because" would be out of place in verses 16 and 17 where ὅτι introduces dependent clauses that clarify and complete rather than explain the reason behind the thought in the main clause.

John 1:14- 17 ESV (with v15 intentionally left out)

> <sup>**14**</sup>And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we
> have seen his glory, glory as of the only Son from the Father, full of
> grace and truth…
>
> <sup>**16**</sup>For from his fullness we have all received, grace
> upon grace.
>
> <sup>**17**</sup>For the law was given through Moses; grace and truth
> came through Jesus Christ.

While they may fulfill different functions, the use of the same conjunction three times in a row does serve to connect these thoughts. However, that connection is not understood to be through the identical function of ὅτι. To determine in what other way they may be connected, it is helpful to examine the context and composition of these verses.

A question immediately arises regarding the composition, particularly the rather odd placement of v15. What is the rationale when a more logical position, between verses 18 and 19 for instance, could make more sense? To answer this question, attention was given to the words “ἡμεῖς πάντες ἐλάβομεν” in v16 –  literally, “we all have received,” with emphasis on the "we."

The witness of John the Baptist in v15 sits between two third person plural pronouns: the “we” of the main clause “we have seen his glory…” (v14) and the “we” of the subordinate clause “we have all received” (v16). These two clauses would have been connected by syntax as well as placement had they not been separated by v15. The positioning of v15 between them strongly suggests that John should be considered as one among the “we.”

It follows that what is written about grace and truth applies to John and to his witness as well. In other words, the grace by which John saw the glory of the Word and bore witness to it, that grace too was received out of the fullness of the Word. Therefore, though John went before in order to announce the coming of the Word, he too was a beneficiary of the grace and truth that flowed from the fulness of the Word.